# How to Loop imacros if error occurs?

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

im trying to run a simple script, loop an imacros over and over but if a link does not exist then move on to the next loop but if the link does exist then just keep running imacros as usual.

This is the script I have made very basic. This is my imacros version

```
 VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FXSET 
 !DATASOURCE check.csv
 TAB T=1
 URL GOTO=http://{{!COL1}}.blogspot.com/
 TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://{{!COL1}}.blogspot.com/
 'if fail start next loop, if not fail keep running macros
 ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}
 SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\iMacros FILE=table.csv
```

This is my javascript version.

```
 const iterations = 100; // Number of times to loop
 var macro;
 macro =  "CODE:";
 macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX" + "\n"; 
 macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
 macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE check.csv" + "\n";
 macro +=  "SET !LOOP 8" + "\n";
 macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3" + "\n";
 macro +=  "set !var1 1" + "\n";
 macro +=  "add !var1 {{!loop}}" + "\n";
 macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!var1}}" + "\n";
 macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n";
 macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://{{!COL1}}.blogspot.com/" + "\n";
 macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE NO" + "\n";
 macro +=  "TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:http://{{!COL1}}.blogspot.com/" + "\n";
 'if link fail start next loop, if not fail keep running macros
 macro +=  "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";
 macro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=c:\iMacros FILE=table.csv" + "\n";
 iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: I tried but Im barely learning javascript so I was only able to create a script that wouldent loop through the csv. if you can help me out would be great.

Comment: I added the javascript version I have came up with.

Comment: Oh dear, I wouldn't exactly call that "using JavaScript" .. but it is JS code (although using `const` is a bit iffy).

Comment: What happens when you run the [JavaScript] code? Is there an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Yeah, that what I was able to come up with. All im trying to do is just loop it to run through my csv and if the link dont exist (fails) to just move on to the next loop if the link exist just keep running the macro as normal and loop.

Comment: Okay, but what happens *now*?

Comment: when I run the javascript it just runs once and stops. When I run it with the link actually exist no error it doesnt execute the next line to extract the data and nor does it loop and keep running it just stops after the first run. And if i make it where the link doesnt exist it just fail ERROR element not found.

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be in the first line, if an error occures, it will ignore it an goes to the next step

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
```